# Convert csv file into python dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, dictionary

I want to convert `A,B,24` type CSV file into a dictionary having format like `{'A':{'B':24}}`.

Comment: I don't know what a A,B,24 type csv file means. Pandas has a nice read csv method, though

Comment: Please show us what you tried and where you got stuck. Did you find the [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) in the standard library yet? Should this happen for every row? Don't answer in the comments, [edit] your question to include this information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an `input.csv` CSV file holding:

```
A,B,24
```

This could be done as follows:

```
import csv

my_dict = {}

with open('input.csv') as f_input:
    for row in csv.reader(f_input):
        my_dict[row[0]] = {row[1] : row[2]}

print my_dict
```

Giving you:

```
{'A': {'B': '24'}}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Martin...it really works :)

Comment: You are welcome! Don't forget to click on the grey tick (under the up/down arrows) to accept the answer as the accepted solution. You should also then get your Scholar badge.